# How to remove section both from header and outline in beamer?

Tags: beamer, sectioning

In the `beamer` presentation I am using `\section*{section name}` to remove the section from the outline. How can I also remove the section from the header (I am using `Singapore` theme)? I tried the following, but it doesn't work:

```
\section*[]{section name}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a redefinition of the internal `\beamer@@ssection*` (original definition in `beamerbasesection.sty`) so `\section*` removes the titles from both the table of contents and the navigation elements in the headline:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Singapore}      

\makeatletter
\long\def\beamer@@ssection*#1{\beamer@section[]{}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Outline}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{A test unstarred section}
\begin{frame} test \end{frame}
\section*{A test starred section}
\begin{frame} test \end{frame}
\section{Another test unstarred section}
\begin{frame} test \end{frame}
\section*{Another test starred section}
\begin{frame} test \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

An image of the outline:

[image]